# Why are these tuple types conjoined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have recreated the error I'm getting in a brandnew Create-React-App repo, source code can be found [here](https://github.com/JDansercoer/TSTest).

As you can see in [MyContext.tsx](https://github.com/JDansercoer/TSTest/blob/master/src/MyContext.tsx), I'm simply adding the result of `useState` to my context. The type of the context is also defined as a tuple by

```
const UDContext = createContext<
  | undefined
  | [
      UserData | undefined,
      React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<UserData | undefined>>
    ]
>(undefined);
```

However, when I try to access the data in [MyComponent.tsx](https://github.com/JDansercoer/TSTest/blob/master/src/MyComponent.tsx) by doing

```
  const [userData] = useUserData();
```

I'm getting the error

```
Property 'username' does not exist on type 'UserData | Dispatch<SetStateAction<UserData | undefined>>'.
```

This to me looks like it is somehow combining the tuple's types to one?

The funny thing: the below code does actually work (it does give a warning that `context` may be undefined, which indeed makes sense).

```
  const context = useUserData();
  const userData = context[0];
```

Exactly the same is happening in [MySetter.tsx](https://github.com/JDansercoer/TSTest/blob/master/src/MySetter.tsx), where the exact error is

```
Not all constituents of type 'UserData | Dispatch<SetStateAction<UserData | undefined>>' are callable.
```

The above "solution" without direct destructuring works here as well.

The only way I can get this to work, is by [explicitly declaring the type](https://github.com/JDansercoer/TSTest/blob/master/src/MyContext.tsx#L31) of the return value of `useUserData`.

**A few sidenotes:**

- This is the `@next` version of Create-React-App
- I had to enable `--downlevelIteration`, or else the destructuring of `useUserData()` was giving `Type '[UserData | undefined, Dispatch<SetStateAction<UserData | undefined>>] | undefined' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.`
- I have a [working example in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-frog-5gk06?file=/src/App.tsx) that gives no issues at all.

Comment: Code sandbox doesn't default to `--strictNullChecks` so `undefined | T` collapses to `T`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a BUG in typescript and I found two open bugs with similar issues [BUG 31613](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31613) and [BUG 40215](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40215)

Apart from the option you mentioned in question (explicit type on return), another option would be to not use tuple destructuring and for your code it would look like:

**MyComponent.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { useUserData } from "./MyContext";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const userData = useUserData();

  if (!userData) {
    return <div>Loading username</div>;
  }

  return <div>{userData[0]?.username}</div>;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

**MySetter.tsx**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useUserData } from "./MyContext";

const MySetter = () => {
  const userData = useUserData();

  // Fakes an API call
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        userData && userData[1]({ username: "FooBar" });
    }, 750);
  });

  return null;
};

export default MySetter;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your context can be also undefined so you need to make checks to make sure you always return *something* from your context. You could create reusable method for creating context thats always *something*, and not `undefined`:

```
function createCtx<T>() {
  const Context = React.createContext<T | undefined>(undefined);
  const useCtx = () => {
    const ctx = React.useContext(Context);
    if (typeof ctx === "undefined") {
      throw new Error("useContext must be inside provider with a value.");
    }
    return ctx;
  };
  return [useCtx, Context.Provider] as const;
};
```

Then use this method as such where you'd probably export `useUserData` and `UserDataContext`

```
const [useUserData, UserDataProvider] = createCtx<[
  UserData | undefined,
  React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<UserData | undefined>>
]>();

const UserDataContext: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState<UserData>();

  return (
    <UserDataProvider value={[userData, setUserData]}>
      {children}
    </UserDataProvider>
  );
};
```

and use it as such in your components

```
export default function App() {
  const [userData] = useUserData();
  
  return (
    <h2>{userData?.username}</h2>
  );
}
```

Not only does this solve your problem, but also gives you reusable method that helps you with other things that you'll surely need.

Cheers.